Why does my domain name display /index.html at the end of it?
I have made a website and am hosting it using Hostinger. Whenever I go to the website the domain name appears and at the end it will have /index.html or /about.html or /contact.html. Now when I go on other websites, they generally don't have the .html at the end but rather just the webpage name for example /home or /about.
I have tried searching this up but can't find any answers on it. I have also checked on browsers on other devices and it does the same. Could it be something to do with the way I've named my files or something with the hosting?
